# Fermion four-point vertex Feynman rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, feynman-diagrams, fermions, software

So I have a theory which has a four-point fermion interaction

$$\mathcal L_{int}=-g(\bar\psi\partial\!\!\!/\psi)(\bar\psi\partial\!\!\!/\psi).$$

I'd like to derive the Feynman rule for the corresponding four-point vertex. My idea is to take the idea from many-loop effective theories and identify the vertex with the 1PI four-point function, which comes from the effective action $\Gamma[\psi,\bar\psi]$ as

$$i\frac{\delta^4\Gamma}{\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi},$$

up to an overall sign that corresponds to the ordering of the derivatives.

But at tree level we have $\Gamma=S$, so I went ahead and computed the vertex rule from the Fourier transform of

$$i\frac{\delta^4S}{\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi\delta\psi\delta\bar\psi},$$

which gave me (I didn't write down the $-g$ in this picture)

[image: feynman rule]

and writing it here just for convenience,

$$-2ig[p\!\!\!/_{1cb}p\!\!\!/_{2ad}-p\!\!\!/_{1ab}p\!\!\!/_{2cd}]$$

Where $p_{1,2}$ are incoming momenta and $a,b,c,d$ are spinor indices. Notice the $(-)$ in between the two external leg permutations, that shows up from the fact that the spinors are Grassmann variables so their derivatives anticommute.

Great. However, when I then went to check it with FeynRules on mathematica, it gave me something very similar but fundamentally different,

$$-2ig[p\!\!\!/_{1cb}p\!\!\!/_{2ad}+p\!\!\!/_{1ab}p\!\!\!/_{2cd}]$$

it has a plus sign in the middle!

This contradicts what I have, and goes against my intuition that would be the Pauli principle, i.e. that the amplitude has to be antisymmetric under the exchange of external legs (identical particle quantum states). What am I missing here? Or is it just FeynRules being incorrect?

EDIT: I tested FeynRules again with a different model, the Thirring model which is very similar,

$$\mathcal L_{int}=-g(\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\psi)(\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi),$$

and the rule given by the software is again with a different symmetry sign from a reference I could find on arXiv (equation 3.5):

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/80770358.pdf

I also found a picture online which shows diagrammatic expressions for various fermion quartic vertices and they all include a minus sign:

[image: various vertices]

The image comes from this ResearchGate page, which explains the diagrams a bit: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Feynman-rules-for-the-fermion-propagator-and-the-interaction-vertices-The-solid-line_fig2_235516668

Comment: Are you sure Mathematica has the same convention for the direction of the momenta?

Comment: @Oбжорoв All a momentum direction change could to is give an overall sign to the rule, not change the symmetry

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti , could you please write down the expression for FeynCalc?

Comment: Again, are you sure the convention for the momenta is the same? For example, you seem convinced that two go in and two go out. But how would the computer know _which_ two you wanted to go in? What if it has all four directed in?

Comment: @knzhou FeynRules does it with momentum pointing along the fermion arrow.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your picture. Normally, when giving Feynman rules one takes all momenta to be incoming or outgoing. Then, where is the time arrow in your diagram (i.e. what particles are incoming and what are outgoing)? Finally,

Comment: *Furthermore, it would be useful to see the FeynRules code you wrote to obtain the Feynman rule. And of course for a given process you can compare the output of FeynArts+FormCalc/FeynCalc with the corresponding FeynRules model to your own derivation. That would be more helpful to see where the discrepancy comes from. I hope this is not too technical for Physics.SE, otherwise one could also move to Mathematica.SE with a [feyncalc tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feyncalc?tab=Newest)